# Stored Procedure Performance Matrix - Performance Test

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-performance

I have got an SP which will be is used for (Billing) statement generation. So it will be taking some 40 parameters from C# backend code.

I tried using Apex SQL Plan but I am not getting the inner matrix of SP(Inside Sp which area uses more cost such details). I cannot directly run SP because the data parameters to be passed are very complex to declare each time.

So how will I do an effective performance test for an SP and generate the result?
Input: Profiler even will be captured and ran manually

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to collect SP performance matrix, so what tool or method I need to do for that?

Comment: could you provide the sp content and also you could cach those parameters in C# as static variables, for faster performance.

Comment: SP accepts multiple parameters as input and based on that statement SP will be generating. I am unable to post the SP in this portal due to my constraints in sharing that.

Comment: What do you mean with "SP will be generating"? Without any code, there most likely won't be any help either.

Comment: SP will be generating means SP will run and update values t specific tables. That action being done after querying so many tables with the parameters passed.